# Obtener tags de conner\tag con api fetch

Tags: php, laravel, api

Estoy implementando el sistema de etiquetas con esta libreria [Laravel Taggable Trait](https://github.com/rtconner/laravel-tagging). Los post con sus respectivos tags los traigo de manera asíncrona usando la API fetch nativa de JavaScript, mi codigo en el controlador es el siguiente:

```php
public function recientes()
{
    $post = Post::orderBy('id','DESC')->with([
        'user',
        'comment',
        'category'
    ])->get();
    return $post;
}
```

Con ese código me retorna los valores correctamente.

Pero cuando quiero agregar los tags:

```php
public function recientes()
{
    $post = Post::orderBy('id','DESC')->with([
        'user',
        'comment',
        'category',
        'tag'
    ])->get();
    return $post;
}
```

La consola me devuele este error:

> ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function App\Post::tag(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\young2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php on line 604 and exactly 1 expected in file C:\xampp\htdocs\young2\vendor\rtconner\laravel-tagging\src\Taggable.php on line 110

Si alguien sabe como puedo obtener estos datos me seria de mucha ayuda.

Comment: Agrega el método de la relación Tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer  eager load se debe llamar a la relación `tagged` y no `tag` como lo estaba haciendo:

```php
public function recientes()
{
    $post = Post::orderBy('id','DESC')->with([
        'user',
        'comment',
        'category',
        'tagged'
    ])->get();
    return $post;
}
```